# Create Object-Class in Swift

Tags: class, object, swift

I'm new at Swift. In Java I can simply make a new Class if I want to make a new object. For example:

```
public class Person{
public Person(String firstname, String lastname){
}
}
```

Then i can simply call the class from another class and initialize a new Person-object and use the getter and setter-methods.

How is that possible in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, this would look like

```
class Person {
    init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You should read [Welcome to Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) and the guides linked there.